# Unable to Run Android project with Google Services Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to run a simple android project showing a Map.

I have followed all the steps in Google Maps [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map) but eclipse just blocks trying to launch the project.

1 - I added the `google-play-services_lib` to my workspace.
2 - I copied that in the workspace.
3 - I created a android project with these:

**Manifest**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> package="com.example.mapasimple"
> android:versionCode="1"
> android:versionName="1.0" >
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="12"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
>  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
>  Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
>  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
>   <uses-feature
>     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
>     android:required="true"/>
>  <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>     <activity
>         android:name=".MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>  <meta-data
>       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="xxxxxxxx-kfjDVu3590eOxjhrVSc"/>
>     <meta-data
> android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
> android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
>  </application>
> </manifest>
> ```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
public class MainActivity extends  Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

4 - I added the library to my project:

[image]

When I try to run the project, eclipse blocks after been a little time processing.

That is what i can see in my project `Java Build Path`.
[image]

`Android Private Libraries` and `Android Dependencies` are checked by default.
If I uncheck one of them, eclipse blocks too. If I uncheck both, eclipse runs the project but this error appears:

03-09 02:45:59.870: W/dalvikvm(10092): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 7875: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap;.setMapType (I)V
03-09 02:45:59.870: D/dalvikvm(10092): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0003
03-09 02:45:59.870: E/dalvikvm(10092): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method com.example.mapasimple.MainActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded
03-09 02:45:59.870: W/dalvikvm(10092): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1130 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;) in Lcom/example/mapasimple/MainActivity;
03-09 02:45:59.870: D/dalvikvm(10092): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000f
03-09 02:45:59.940: D/AndroidRuntime(10092): Shutting down VM
03-09 02:45:59.960: W/dalvikvm(10092): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a641f8)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapasimple/com.example.mapasimple.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1960)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4447)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:264)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1836)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at com.example.mapasimple.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1092)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    ... 11 more
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:581)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4236)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    ... 21 more
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-09 02:45:59.970: E/AndroidRuntime(10092):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571)

I tried these different things with no success:

- Adding `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>`in Manifest.xml
- uninstall and install again the `Google Play Services`.
- Changing `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` to `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` in activity_main.xml
- Deleting the workspace and do all the process again in a new workspace.
- Just adding the `google-play-services.jar` as external Jar Library.
- I clean and build the project in each modification.
- I changed the SDK Target from `google-play-services_lib` and my project from 4.2.2 to 5.0.1 without no success.
- I did all these steps in another computer.
- The minimum AndroidSDK is API 12.

I am working with Eclipse Luna in Ubuntu.
Please I read several answers for this issue and nothing is working for me. Any idea

**UPDATED FOR THE @RUBEN LUZ  ANSWER**

> ```
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.Window;
> import android.view.WindowManager;
> import android.widget.Toast;
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
> public class MainActivity extends  Activity{
> GoogleMap googleMap;
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
>             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>      initilizeMap();
>      }
>     private void initilizeMap() {
>         if (googleMap == null) {
>             googleMap = ((MapFragment) ((Activity) getApplicationContext()).getFragmentManager()
>                     .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
>  // check if map is created successfully or not
>             if (googleMap == null) {
>                 Toast.makeText(
>                         getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(),
>                         "googlemap null",
>                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>              }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

**UPDATED for @PREDACTOR answer**

now seems that android can not find the MainActivity class. I have remake the project, doing again all the steps and making it again in a new workspace but this error appears always:

> 03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapasimple/com.example.mapasimple.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mapasimple.MainActivity
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1884)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4447)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mapasimple.MainActivity
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1875)
>   03-08 22:10:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17429):    ... 11 more

Comment: The very first line of your error is pointing to inflating the view, line #2. Try putting the map fragment in a Linearlayout

Comment: Or try SupportMapFragment in your xml.....

Comment: I tried that and the same error appears.

Comment: The layout or supportmapfragment? android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: i tried the layout, let me try the supportmapfragment

Comment: Exactly the same error appears just changing the `unable to instantiate com...MapFragment` instead `com....Support.Map.Fragment`. I have to remember you that i only can run the project uncheking the `Android Dependencies` neither `Private Libraries` . Maybe this info helps you to find a solution for me.thanks

Comment: use Google API 21 Instead of Android 5.0.1

Comment: I tried...same error

Answer (score 2):

Inside Main Activity add this

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
```

In the onCreate method add this

```
setUpMapIfNeeded();
```

under the onCreate method, add this

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
    // map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getExtendedMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    }

}
```

Your fragment layout should look like this

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I cant run it. This error appears get I add your Code `The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity`. I have imported the `import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;`

Comment: Make sure you also import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Answer (score 1):

Show the code that you use to initialize the map. The logcat says "Error inflating class fragment" so there is a problem when creating the map. your xml file looks fine the code i dont know.

But it should look like

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                            .getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.map_toast),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

this is a code that i use to initialize the map inside a fragment, change it to you needs

Answer (score 1):

try this code it work with me

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapsss"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


<permission
    android:name="com.example.osman.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.osman.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>  
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

  </application>

 </manifest>
```

mainactivity

```
mainactivity.java
package com.example.mapsss;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

GoogleMap mMap;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMap = ((MapFragment)   getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}
}
```

main

```
main.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >


<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: ClassNotFoundException for MainActivity. Any idea?